# Scanning strings with whitespace into wchar_t

Tags: c

I need to scan a string of wchar_t. The input can have spaces in it, and i want to scan until new line.

In order to scan a string of wchar_t, i would use placeholder %ls. The problem is, this does not include whitespace. I tried scanning with %[^\n], but this gives a warning about trying to scan char into wchar_t, and gives corrupted output.

This is my code snippet:

```
wchar_t addressInput[ADDRESS_MAX];
printf("\nPlease enter your street address, to get distance to articles.\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]", addressInput);
printf("%ls", addressInput);
```

Currently, this does not do the print. I checked the addressInput poiner via a debugger, and it is more or less corrupt data.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wscanf/

Comment: You probably need [`wscanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwscanf.html)

Comment: It's just, that when i jues wscanf like this: "wscanf(L" %[^\n]", addressInput);" then, when compiled, just skips over the input, not waiting for user input like regular scanf.

Comment: Also you might like to read the [UTF-8 Everywhere manifesto](https://utf8everywhere.org/), rethink your character strategy and use plain old `char` :)

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: @NathanOliver it's c, i just thought this would be relevant for both languages.

Comment: In C++ you'd use `std::wstring address; std::getline(std::wcin, address)`

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for necroposting.

But you have to add an `l` after `%`. And you will have to add `L` before a string literal to indicate it is wide.

```
wchar_t addressInput[ADDRESS_MAX];
wprintf(L"\nPlease enter your street address, to get distance to articles.\n");
wscanf(L" %l[^\n]", addressInput);
wprintf(L"%ls", addressInput);
```

Hope this helps